# Абзацы внутри монолога, какое правило

Tags: прямая-речь, оформление-текста, абзац

Имеется длинный монолог. Либо речь определённого персонажа в диалоге.
Можно ли её разбивать на абзацы? Или все фразы только в подбор?
Обычные правила по оформлению прямой речи найти несложно, но там отсутствует такое.

Каким правилом нужно руководствоваться, где его найти? (Разбивка авторскими словами, чтобы монолог не выглядел "кирпичом", исключена.)

Comment: Очень важный вопрос ,и до сих пор не решен.

Answer (score 3):

Не раз встречала в книгах разделение монологов на абзацы. Иногда сама запутывалась: думала, что читаю уже авторский текст, и только через несколько страниц до меня доходило, что это всё ещё реплика персонажа.

Также в некоторых книжках запутывалась в диалогах, где в принципе нет никакой необходимости разделять реплику на абзацы. Было такое, что две реплики подряд (каждая с новой строчки, начинается с тире) принадлежали одному персонажу. Это ещё и ухудшалось отсутствием слов автора, которые хоть как-нибудь помогли бы разобраться, кто есть кто.

Это я всё к чему: не волнуйтесь сильно из-за этих абзацев. Разбивайте так, как вам нравится. Да, это немного неудобно. В помощь вам выделение другим шрифтом.

Answer (score 3):

В литературных произведениях используют три решения подобных ситуаций.

1. Просто пишут абзацы. Подразумевается, что ясно по контексту, кто говорит. Это самый неуклюжий, но наиболее популярный вариант.
2. Оформляют прямую речь при помощи кавычек или отступов (есть и другие варианты: курсив, шрифт, но это извращение). Редко встречается, но уже нагляднее.
3. Разбивают абзацы прямой речи авторскими вставками, либо репликами от других героев. Тогда мы имеем отдельные абзацы, которые можно выделять тире. Но это требует вмешательства в текст, его изменения.

Answer (score 2):

В диалоге, когда каждая фраза начинается с нового абзаца и тире, границы прямой речи показывают именно абзацы. Поэтому если Вы разобьёте текст, у Вас получится первый абзац – слова героя, а все последующие – слова автора. Разбивать на абзацы можно речь в кавычках. Попробуйте перестроить немного эту часть повествования, чтобы заключить речь героя именно в кавычки, если она действительно большая и требует разделения на абзацы. В противном случае – нужно делать один абзац, чтобы читателю было понятно, кто и сколько говорит.

Comment: " если Вы разобьёте текст, у Вас получится первый абзац – слова героя, а все последующие – слова автора". Это неправда. Прямая речь может разбиваться на абзацы.Её конец тогда определяют по контексту или увеличенному отступу в конце. Вариант с кавычками логичнее, но обычно обходятся без них.

Comment: Если монологу предшествуют слова автора, без установки от автора на абзац, можно начать речь в подбор — с кавычек.

Answer (score 1):

**Как по мне**, это оформление — соглашусь здесь со многими — остаётся на усмотрение автора. Чаще всего да, я наблюдал многоабзацные реплики с разделением на обычные абзацы — и тогда приходилось выяснять по контексту, где идёт разделение на абзацы, а где начинаются слова автора.
**Лично я** предлагаю два варианта развития событий: либо вставлять после длинной реплики пустую строку, чтобы чётко определять читателю, где заканчивается первая (но, **как по мне**, выглядеть это будет нелепо); либо каждый последующий абзац реплики начинать на том же уровне, что и первый, то есть как будто бы перед ним стоит тире, но, естественно, тире нет (**я лично** предпочитаю оформлять именно так, ведь тогда абзац начинается чуть правее, чем обычно, и это сразу же приводит к мысли, что он является продолжением реплики).

Answer (score 1):

Розенталь:

7. Если передается длинный рассказ со многими абзацами, то тире ставится только перед первым абзацем (ни перед промежуточными абзацами, ни перед последним тире не ставятся):

— Работа нашей экспедиции проходила так, — начал свой рассказ учёный-геолог. — Был разработан подробный план, намечены маршруты… [Продолжает рассказ.]

Таковы предварительные результаты экспедиции.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=161